# Add prefix and suffix in existing column and add that as a separate new column in Polars rust

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I have a DataFrame df:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | value |
| 3 | value |

now for Column A, I want to add prefix "test_" and suffix "_new" as a new column "TEST".
Output should be:

| A (i64) | B | TEST |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | value | test_1_new |
| 3 | value | test_2_new |

Please help me!!. I have used concat function but it is not working.

```
I have used below code:
 let prefix = "prefix_";

    // Apply a closure to add the prefix to each value in the column
    let new_df = df.apply(|col: &Series| {
        // Ensure the column is of Int type
        if let Ok(int_col) = col.i32() {
            // Create a new Series with modified values
            let new_values = int_col
                .into_iter()
                .map(|value| format!("{}{}", prefix, value))
                .collect::<Vec<_>>();
            Ok(Series::new(new_values))
        } else {
            // Return the original column as-is for non-Int columns
            Ok(col.clone())
        }
```

The error I am getting is:
the trait bound `&Result<&mut polars::prelude::DataFrame, PolarsError>: IntoSeries` is not satisfied

Comment: Please provide more details about what you tried. In particular, edit your post to add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have used concat function in rust and tried but it is not working, Do you have any other method?

Comment: Please edit your post to *show the code* you use, instead of describing it. Currently, it's impossible to help you even if we want to! And, do not forget to "minimize" it as described in the article I linked earlier. It's important both for you and for people trying to help you. Also include the (full) error messages.

Comment: I know it's a bit annoying, but please *edit* your question to add all that information. The purpose of all this is, among other things, to help future readers who wonder if they have the same problem quickly have an answer. Also, the problem you have is easy to solve so, once you have done that, you will get a relevant answer quickly (but that wouldn't have been possible if you didn't post your code :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not handle a possible error. Methods like [`DataFrame::apply`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/frame/struct.DataFrame.html#method.apply) return `Result<&mut DataFrame, PolarsError>`, not just a `&mut DataFrame`. See the [Rust book's chapter on error handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-00-error-handling.html) for more details but, as a quick-and-dirty solution, you can `unwrap` the dataframe from the `Result`:

```rust
let new_df = df.apply(|col: &Series| ...).unwrap();
```

Since you do not include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) nor the full error message (with context, line numbering, ...) but just the name of the error, it's hard to give you more details on how to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can [cast the column `A` to `datatypes::DataType::String`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/series/struct.Series.html#method.cast) type and then use the [`apply_to_buffer`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/chunked_array/struct.ChunkedArray.html#method.apply_to_buffer) API to construct the new string based on your prefix and suffix.

```
use polars::prelude::*;
use std::fmt::Write;

fn main() {
    // Create dummy DataFrame
    let mut df = df!(
        "A" => &[1i64, 2],
        "B" => &["value", "value"]
    )
    .unwrap();
    
    // Create new column named 'TEST' based on the column 'A'
    let new_col = df
        .column("A")
        .unwrap()
        .cast(&datatypes::DataType::String)
        .unwrap()
        .str()
        .unwrap()
        .apply_to_buffer(|current_value, buffer| {
            write!(buffer, "test_{}_new", current_value).unwrap();
        })
        .with_name("TEST");

    let new_df = df.with_column(new_col).unwrap();
    println!("{new_df}")
}
```

This will produce the following DataFrame:

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬───────┬────────────┐
│ A   ┆ B     ┆ TEST       │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ i64 ┆ str   ┆ str        │
╞═════╪═══════╪════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ value ┆ test_1_new │
│ 2   ┆ value ┆ test_2_new │
└─────┴───────┴────────────┘
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I'm not familiar with the rust API, but in Python, it would be

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.concat_str(
        [pl.lit("test"), pl.col("A").cast(pl.Utf8), pl.lit("new")], separator="_"
    ).alias("TEST")
)
```

Comment: I am converting the whole python code to rust, In python i have this code.